# Vim - mapping a text string to specific buffer

Tags: buffers

I like to know how I can connect/map a specific string to a desired buffer.

Let's say I have the following text files:

- file1:
  Dog
  Cat
- file2:
  Milk

Now, the 2 files are located at different dirs, and my goal is as follows:

1. Mouse left click while cursor on "Cat" pops up file2 content.
2. Mouse right click will bring the user back to file1 content.

Thanks!

Edit:

Let me introduce a more detailed view containing the association process:

1. Each user has 2 files in his directory. These files are actually reports that created throughout some user analysis.
2. The files look as follows:

- Section 1:

  - <group_name1>
  - group_name1 additional details (some detail about this specific group)
- Section 2:

  - <group_name2>
  - group_name2 additional details
    .
    .
    Now, pre-proccesing (via TCL/Python/awk) over these files I've:

- <group_name1>
- <group_name2>
  .
  .

Once user click on <group_name1> - a new window will popup with the additional info of <group_name1>. Once he uses the mouse right-click, he goes back to the main window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is the association determined? Can it be done programmatically or must it be specified manually?

Comment: The association is determined dynamically - it depends on pre-proccessing bunch of text files.  Different users will experiene different associations..

Comment: Without more detail about the association, it will be hard to provide anything beyond a high-level sketch. If it must be mouse-behavior, you would want to look in to (conditionally? `<expr>`?) re-mapping mouse-clicks.

Comment: Please see original massage edit. Thx..

Comment: Stop trying to do stuff with mouse clicks in Vim.   Keeping your hands on the keyboard is more common in Vim.  

I think you want to set the `includeexpr` setting.   Please do `:help includeexpr`.   It is a function that will be called when hitting `gf` with the cursor over the filename, but only if the filename doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChrisHeithoff while it may be more common, we try not to discourage folks from doing what they want, unless there are serious problems that may arise (in which case we call those out). Your tone in that comment comes across as a little less than kind. Pointing out alternatives is of course welcome, though you could flesh out the use of gf and other settings to an answer.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for pointing the tone of my comment.   I believe that the user's LeftMouse operation could be done with hitting `gf`, with a function defined as `includeexpr`.  This function would be called only if the word under the cursor is not an existing file.  It would return a filename based on some Vimscript that could get the line below the cursor with `getline()` and parse the line appropriately.    Returning to the original file is similar to the native `ctrl-o` Vim operation.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
nmap <RightMouse> :new <cWORD><CR>
```

Now you might need to process `<cWORD>` or do something else.
Learn about `if`,`expand` and maybe you will need to select,copy and paste the content.

I tried in neovim. Not sure if matters.